# How to make autocomplete class in sublime text 3?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, sublimetext3

How do I get when I type `container` in the sublime, this appears autocomplete : `<div class="container"></div>`. 
I had installed package, but it's not working

Thank you

**Update** :

I follow this tutorial : https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete/

I try in terminal windows like this : https://postimg.org/image/qt3zf3v0t/

Then, I try autocomplete in sublime, but it still does not work

Comment: did you used [emmet](http://emmet.io/)?

Comment: @Abhishek gurjar, No, I using sublime text 3

Comment: it is extension for sublime please check.

Comment: @Abhishek gurjar, I update my question. I've tried the tutorial, but it does not work

Comment: Based on your image, you didn't clone the repository into the correct location. You're better off using PackageControl to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime, these are known as snippets.

You can create a new one by selecting **Tools > Developer > New Snippet...**, where you'll find a skeleton to help define your new snippet. Based on your question, I think you'd want something like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<div class="container"></div>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>container</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

The code defined inside the `<![CDATA[…]]>` section is the actual snippet, the full text you want the autocomplete to result in.

The tabTrigger defines the biggest word you have to type for the content to be suggested. In this case, typing a sub-word of 'container' (`c`, `co`, `con`, ... `container`) will trigger the content to appear in the drop-down box.

Save the file to the default location with the extension `.sublime-snippet` for it to take effect.

More information is available in the [unofficial sublime docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).